# How to draw an ongoing image calculation in SDL (C++)?

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a function that calculates a basic Julia fractal. It works fine and I can show it in a SDL window. it works as I expect. However I want to be able to see the Julia fractal while is it being created.

The fractal is calculated in a simple forx,fory fashion. So it is not a recursive function. At the end of the loop I color the pixels and draw the ones that are in the range of the Julia description. The pixel drawing writes to the main Sdl surface *screen.

Is there a way to display an ongoing calculation in an SDL app? I want to be able to see the progression of the image. I realize that this might require a different type of programming approach. I am just trying to figure out what my options are.

Comment: You could draw a frame every X iterations of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to display your image after each pixel or each row of your calculation. Optionally you can only update your image if the time since the last update is larger than a given minimum value (e.g. 1/60.0 s)

A more complicated solution would be to separate rendering and computation into separate threads. This offers various advantages: The actual computation is not intermingled with the rendering part and the display (and other UI-related functions) does not depend on the computation speed.

Comment: grep, I tried the updating after each pixel, however it is dead slow. I am using SDL_UpdateRect inside the loop. I am guessing that that is not an efficient way. I am also going to scale the update box when I am back on it. Can you recommend another function or method for updating in a way that works inside a cpu intense loop? I am also interested in separating the display and calculation.  Can you please recommend some terminology there? At the moment I am using the standard Sdl surface. Maybe moving to Opengl can speed things up for me?